# Exceptions when trying to get location

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I want to get the current position (longitude and longitude) but I am getting some errors in the code.

> `1. map_view` , `activity_maintv_location` ,`cur_position` cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {

private MapView mapView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Getting reference to MapView
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view  );

    // Setting Zoom Controls on MapView
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Getting the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Getting Current Location
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if(location!=null){
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

    // Getting latitude
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    // Getting longitude
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
    tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );

    // Creating an instance of GeoPoint corresponding to latitude and longitude
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude * 1E6), (int)(longitude*1E6));

    // Getting MapController
    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

    // Locating the Geographical point in the Map
    mapController.animateTo(point);

    // Applying a zoom
    mapController.setZoom(15);

    // Redraw the map
    mapView.invalidate();

    // Getting list of overlays available in the map
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

    // Creating a drawable object to represent the image of mark in the map
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cur_position);

    // Creating an instance of ItemizedOverlay to mark the current location in the map
    CurrentLocationOverlay currentLocationOverlay = new CurrentLocationOverlay(drawable);

    // Creating an item to represent a mark in the overlay
    OverlayItem currentLocation = new OverlayItem(point, "Current Location", "Latitude : " + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);

    // Adding the mark to the overlay
    currentLocationOverlay.addOverlay(currentLocation);

    // Clear Existing overlays in the map
    mapOverlays.clear();

    // Adding new overlay to map overlay
    mapOverlays.add(currentLocationOverlay);

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

Comment: Post your layout xml files..

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have grabbed this code and pasted it in your project's Activity. You seem to have, however, not added the other resources. If this is from a website, post a link to that website in the OP.

For instance, consider the error on `map_view` as stated in the OP refers to this line of code:

`mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);`

And the error for `cur_position` refers to this line:

`Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cur_position);`

Verify that a `MapView` with the id of `map_view` exists in your layout XML `activity_main`. As for the `Drawable cur_position`, ensure that you have image resource (I am assuming) in either of the `Drawable` folders in your Project.

The other `activity_maintv_location` doesn't appear in the code posted above, but either of the suggestions above will fix that one too.

Answer (score 0):

try this and your Activity must be  implements like this `implements LocationListener {`

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
        lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());

        Log.i(TAG, "Lattitude:" + lat);
        Log.i(TAG, "Longitude:" + lng);

        Toast.makeText( this, "Current location:\nLatitude: " + lat + "\n" + "Longitude: " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // create geo point
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));         
        MapController controller = mapview.getController();  
        controller.animateTo(point);
        controller.setZoom(13);     
        mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);        

        drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);    
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");    
        itemizedOverlay = new SimpleItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapview);  
        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);    


        mapOverlays = mapview.getOverlays();

        mapview.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);  
        mapview.invalidate();           

    } else {
        System.out.println("Location not avilable");
    }
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
```